# Undefined method strftime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying a implement a time field form in rails. I am running to this issue, on the new routes the forms displays and I can make submissions but on the edit route I get this ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `strftime' for "23:25":String

```
<%= form_with(model: shop) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :opening_time %>
    <%= form.time_field :opening_time %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :closing_time %>
    <%= form.time_field :closing_time %>
```

```
# GET /shops/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /shops
  # POST /shops.json
  def create
    @shop = Shop.new(shop_params)
     @shop.seller = current_seller

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shop.save
        format.html { redirect_to @shop, notice: 'Shop was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shop }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @shop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /shops/1
  # PATCH/PUT /shops/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shop.update(shop_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @shop, notice: 'Shop was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shop }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @shop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue happen because your `date` are saved like String, maybe you need parse this string to DateTime and after use the `strptime` method.

**Example with rails console:**

Error:

```rb
irb(main):006:0> "23:25".strftime
Traceback (most recent call last): 
   1: from (irb):6
NoMethodError (undefined method `strftime' for "23:25":String)
Did you mean?  strip
```

Solution:

```rb
irb(main):007:0> "23:25".to_datetime.strftime
=> "2021-01-12T23:25:00+00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the time format using `value` key to `time_field` helper

```
<%= form.time_field :opening_time, value: '%H:%M' %>
```

[time_field](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-time_field) helper

> The default value is generated by trying to call strftime with “%T.%L” on the object's value. It is still possible to override that by passing the “value” option.